# Getting PDO exception 42000 on PDO SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

This has been bugging me for a fair amount of time now and I can't seem to find were the issue lies. This is the query I'm stuck at:

```sql
$stmt2 = $conn->prepare('SELECT a.[zone], b.[source_external_subscriber_id], SUM(b.[source_customer_cost]) AS [total]
    FROM billing_zones a INNER JOIN cdr b 
    ON a.[id] = b.[source_customer_billing_zone_id] 
    WHERE destination_account_id = :destinationId 
    GROUP BY b.[source_external_subscriber_id], a.[zone]');
$stmt2->execute(array('destinationId' => $destinationId));
```

The message I get:

> Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '[zone], b.[source_external_subscriber_id], SUM(b.[source_customer_cost] AS [tota' at line 1 in /home/integracion.php:14

Comment: That looks more like an SQL Server query. Or does MySQL accept square brackets for delimited identifiers?

Comment: Show FULL error mesage text.

Comment: I am not really sure, it is the first time I'm using PDO querys. So ido they have different JOIN syntax as well?

Comment: @Akina Sorry, I forgot! Up it is :)

Comment: If so then @Cid gives you the answer already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Squared brackets (`[...]`) are for Microsoft SQL Server, not for MySQL/MariaDB. You need to use backticks instead

```
--       v----v------- check this
SELECT a.`zone` ...
```

---

Note that you can use double quotes too if you enable `SQL_MODE=ANSI_QUOTE`. Double quotes are SQL-92 standard and should be compatible with any DBMS

Comment: Hey @Cid If I were to do the same but with tables on two different databases, would it then be:   `Select * from Database1.\`dbo\`.Table1 tab1
join Database2.\`dbo\`.Table2 tab2 on tab1.ID = tab2.ID`